# Auto check "Use Storyboard ID" in Identity Inspector for any controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Is it possible to set the "auto check" for "Use Storyboard ID" option in Identity inspector for any view controller or navigation controller? As I have to check that option each time I add new View controller or Navigation controller in my apps storyboard. I wonder if is there any setting in x-code to enable this option as well? [image: Auto check for this option]

Comment: Unfortunately, the requirement you are looking for is not possible. There is no shortcut for making restoration id from storyboard id.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina, Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Hrshil Auto check “Use Storyboard ID” is used when you want to access your viewController from navigation stack or model presenter stack.

Comment: Thanks @Sandip, But I wanted to use it each time I add a viewController.

Comment: Ok @Hrshil i have to R&D for that.